# Asterisk call dropped after 32 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, ip, sip, asterisk

I'm new to Asterisk; I'm using Asterisk 11 and an X-Lite client softphone. I get a successful connection, but after 32 seconds, the call gets dropped and the connection is severed.

```
WARNING[3830]: chan_sip.c:4175 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission YjExYmF for seqno 2 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 31999ms with no response
WARNING[3896]: chan_sip.c:4204 retrans_pkt: Hanging up call YjExYmF - no reply to out critical packet (see See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions). 
  == Spawn extension (TextMenu, start, 2) exited non-zero on 'SIP/Sip01-00000000'
```

I have a very basic sip.conf file

```
[general]
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
port=5060

[Line](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=LocalSets

[Sip01](Line)
secret=password

[Sip02](Line)
secret=password

[Sip03](Line)
secret=password
```

sip logs from "sip set debug on" (Note, I've hidden the tail end of my ip addresses with XX.XXX)
I am pretty sure it is a problem with the transfer from 54.187.XX.XXX to 172.31.XX.XXX, but I do not know how to config this

```
sip set debug on
SIP Debugging enabled
*CLI>
<--- SIP read from UDP:208.181.XX.XXX:51732 --->
INVITE sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ffdd1930cfcc0045-1---d8754z-;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:Sip01@208.181.XX.XXX:51732>
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: replaces
User-Agent: X-Lite 4.7.0 73589-02bfb00b-W
Content-Length: 305

v=0
o=- 13050786034548600 1 IN IP4 208.181.XX.XXX
s=X-Lite release 4.7.0 stamp 73589
c=IN IP4 208.181.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 55020 RTP/AVP 125 0 100 9 8 101
a=rtpmap:125 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:125 useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:100 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv
<------------->
--- (13 headers 12 lines) ---
Sending to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732 (no NAT)
Sending to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732 (no NAT)
Using INVITE request as basis request - YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
Found peer 'Sip01' for 'Sip01' from 208.181.XX.XXX:51732

<--- Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732 --->
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ffdd1930cfcc0045-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as6e6be255
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
WWW-Authenticate: Digest algorithm=MD5, realm="asterisk", nonce="6969372e"
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog 'YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE' in 32000 ms (Method: INVITE)

<--- SIP read from UDP:208.181.XX.XXX:51732 --->
ACK sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ffdd1930cfcc0045-1---d8754z-;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as6e6be255
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 1 ACK
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (8 headers 0 lines) ---

<--- SIP read from UDP:208.181.XX.XXX:51732 --->
INVITE sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
Contact: <sip:Sip01@208.181.XX.XXX:51732>
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, NOTIFY, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, INFO
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: replaces
User-Agent: X-Lite 4.7.0 73589-02bfb00b-W
Authorization: Digest username="Sip01",realm="asterisk",nonce="6969372e",uri="sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX",response="ea76602a3f2458bf83c85c2e6115a1bf",algorithm=MD5
Content-Length: 305

v=0
o=- 13050786034548600 1 IN IP4 208.181.XX.XXX
s=X-Lite release 4.7.0 stamp 73589
c=IN IP4 208.181.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 55020 RTP/AVP 125 0 100 9 8 101
a=rtpmap:125 opus/48000/2
a=fmtp:125 useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:100 speex/16000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv
<------------->
--- (14 headers 12 lines) ---
Sending to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732 (no NAT)
Using INVITE request as basis request - YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
Found peer 'Sip01' for 'Sip01' from 208.181.XX.XXX:51732
  == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
Found RTP audio format 125
Found RTP audio format 0
Found RTP audio format 100
Found RTP audio format 9
Found RTP audio format 8
Found RTP audio format 101
Found unknown media description format opus for ID 125
Found audio description format speex for ID 100
Found audio description format telephone-event for ID 101
Capabilities: us - (gsm|ulaw|alaw|h263|testlaw), peer - audio=(ulaw|alaw|speex16|g722)/video=(nothing)/text=(nothing), combined - (ulaw|alaw)
Non-codec capabilities (dtmf): us - 0x1 (telephone-event|), peer - 0x1 (telephone-event|), combined - 0x1 (telephone-event|)
Peer audio RTP is at port 208.181.XX.XXX:55020
Looking for 201 in LocalSets (domain 54.187.XX.XXX)
list_route: hop: <sip:Sip01@208.181.XX.XXX:51732>

<--- Transmitting (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732 --->
SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
    -- Executing [201@LocalSets:1] Goto("SIP/Sip01-00000000", "TestMenu,start,1") in new stack
    -- Goto (TestMenu,start,1)
    -- Executing [start@TestMenu:1] Answer("SIP/Sip01-00000000", "") in new stack
Audio is at 11910
Adding codec 100003 (ulaw) to SDP
Adding codec 100004 (alaw) to SDP
Adding non-codec 0x1 (telephone-event) to SDP

<--- Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

<------------>
Retransmitting #1 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
    -- Executing [start@TestMenu:2] BackGround("SIP/Sip01-00000000", "enter-ext-of-person") in new stack
    -- <SIP/Sip01-00000000> Playing 'enter-ext-of-person.gsm' (language 'en')
Retransmitting #2 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
[Jul 25 18:20:36] NOTICE[3952][C-00000000]: res_rtp_asterisk.c:4100 ast_rtp_read: Unknown RTP codec 126 received from '208.181.XX.XXX:55020'
    -- Executing [start@TestMenu:3] WaitExten("SIP/Sip01-00000000", "60") in new stack
Retransmitting #3 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
Retransmitting #4 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
Retransmitting #5 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
Retransmitting #6 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
Retransmitting #7 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
Retransmitting #8 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
Retransmitting #9 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
Retransmitting #10 (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 208.181.XX.XXX:51732;branch=z9hG4bK-d8754z-ae549b31d20fda42-1---d8754z-;received=208.181.XX.XXX;rport=51732
From: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
To: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 2 INVITE
Server: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:201@172.31.XX.XXX:5060>
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 260

v=0
o=root 696150323 696150323 IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
s=Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
c=IN IP4 172.31.XX.XXX
t=0 0
m=audio 11910 RTP/AVP 0 8 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sendrecv

---
[Jul 25 18:21:05] WARNING[3943]: chan_sip.c:4175 retrans_pkt: Retransmission timeout reached on transmission YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE for seqno 2 (Critical Response) -- See https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions
Packet timed out after 31999ms with no response
[Jul 25 18:21:05] WARNING[3943]: chan_sip.c:4204 retrans_pkt: Hanging up call YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE - no reply to our critical packet (see https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/SIP+Retransmissions).
  == Spawn extension (TestMenu, start, 3) exited non-zero on 'SIP/Sip01-00000000'
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog 'YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE' in 32000 ms (Method: INVITE)
set_destination: Parsing <sip:Sip01@208.181.XX.XXX:51732> for address/port to send to
set_destination: set destination to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732
Reliably Transmitting (no NAT) to 208.181.XX.XXX:51732:
BYE sip:Sip01@208.181.XX.XXX:51732 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.31.XX.XXX:5060;branch=z9hG4bK48b15afb;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
To: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 102 BYE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 11.11.0
Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="Sip01", realm="asterisk", algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:54.187.XX.XXX", nonce="6969372e", response="256e79bf45a166dfb059c99bccb14689"
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: No user responding
X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 18
Content-Length: 0


---

<--- SIP read from UDP:208.181.XX.XXX:51732 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.31.XX.XXX:5060;branch=z9hG4bK48b15afb;rport=5060;received=54.187.XX.XXX
Contact: <sip:Sip01@208.181.XX.XXX:51732>
To: "Chris"<sip:Sip01@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=f77d6c22
From: <sip:201@54.187.XX.XXX>;tag=as768cf196
Call-ID: YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE
CSeq: 102 BYE
User-Agent: X-Lite release 4.7.0 stamp 73589 02bfb00b-W
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
SIP Response message for INCOMING dialog BYE arrived
Really destroying SIP dialog 'YzA0NmM5NjY5MzU0ZmU0YWM4NGZiMDJhY2ZjZGU0MzE' Method: INVITE
sip set debug off
SIP Debugging Disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your issue has been fixed. But the 200 OK is being retransmitted because its not receiving the ACK message.

Typically as per protocol the ACK is sent to the Contact address in the 200 OK. But in your case it seems to be behind a NAT and for that reason the ACK should be sent to the NAT Address from where the 200 OK was received.

I hope this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Retransmit mean other side can't get packet or not want respond on it.

Considering xlite proved worked softphone, most likly your router or router on destination have firewall or sip-ALG enabled and block packets

If asterisk not got response from other side, it consider call failed and disconnect.